# Maintaining the aspect ratio of Image using CSS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, dimension

I have images which dimension is  (900x512). As I am going to make it responsive so images need to adjust within that screen width maintaining aspect ratio!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
<img src="..." style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```

this will keep the aspect-ratio. `height: auto` will make sure the `height` is not set elsewhere (as mentioned by *cale_b*)

Comment: Technically, it will not, if the height is set elsewhere.  You would also want a "height: auto;" in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap, you can add the `img-responsive` class to your images.

This class applies the following css properties

- Max-width: 100%
- Height: auto
- Display: block

The markup would look like this

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="My image" >
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by only setting a width or a height in your css.

```
.image{
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the height is set anywhere else. You would also want a "height: auto;" to prevent height from being fixed and width being fluid.

Comment: true but then you will be disregarding the point that you should ONLY be setting width or height and not both. If you have controle over your own CSS, then this is a valid, and actually the only option. As soon as you set height and width, it will not work.